# How to export CUSTOMERS from 1.3.1 to 1.9.1.? Is it even possible?

Tags: importexport

I've tried and I've tried and I've tried...

I do an EXPORT of CUSTOMERS from an older version of Magento (1.3.1) to the latest (1.9.1) but when I try to IMPORT it on the 1.9.1 version - it always give me Errors. I figured out already that I have to change website to _website and it seems to be better when I select to do the EXPORT without apostrophes. It seems that some of the customer's data is so long that it 'spills' over to the next row in the CSV - is this possible? What can I try to make the EXPORT/IMPORT work?

Here are the Errors I currently get on the IMPORT side:

```
Invalid value for 'group_id' in rows: 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25, 26, 27, 30, 32, 34, 35, 37, 40, 42, 43, 44, 46, 47, 49, 50, 52, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 64, 65, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 86, 88, 89, 90, 91, 93, 95, 96, 97, 98

E-mail is not specified in rows: 2, 6, 29, 33, 41, 53, 63, 67, 77, 87

E-mail is invalid in rows: 13, 16, 22, 24, 28, 31, 36, 38, 39, 45, 48, 51, 66, 73, 75, 79, 85, 92, 94, 99, 100

 File is totally invalid. Please fix errors and re-upload file

Checked rows: 100, checked entities: 90, invalid rows: 100, total errors: 100
```

Comment: Always start with the first error message, the others are often followup errors. In this case: you have to create the same customer groups as in the old store before importing.

Comment: I looked under Customers - Customer Groups in the Admin panel and both have the EXACT same groups there...Any other suggestions?